# How to add days to Datetime value in vba excel

Tags: vba, excel, date, datetime

I have a table where a date is in the Format 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:nn:ss' like 02.09.2017 08:20:00.

When i test if the Date is really a date with IsDate(sh.Cells(rw.Row, 4)) the result is true.

Now i want to add to each date 5 days which should be done with DateAdd("d", 5, sh.Cells(rw.Row, 4)).

However, when i try that i get the error message:

> 13: Types incompatible

Here is my code.

```
Sub test()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim RowCount As Integer

    RowCount = 0
    Set sh = Sheets("Table1")

    For Each rw In sh.Rows

        If sh.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If  

       date = DateAdd("d", 1, sh.Cells(rw.Row, 4))
       Debug.Print date

    Next rw
End Sub
```

**Update:**

This now worked for me:

```
  With sh
    RowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row  '<-- get last row in column 'A"

    For i = 4 To 4 'RowCount
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then Exit For

        start_date = .Cells(i, 4) - 10    '10 days you want to look back
    Next i
  End With
```

Don't know why i got the error message before with the same code.

Comment: 1) "date" is a reserved keyword. 2) Have you tried `DateAdd("d", 1, CDate(sh.Cells(rw.Row, 4)))`?

Comment: How about `sh.Cells(rw.Row, 4) + 5` ?

Comment: @KostasK. 1)changed it, but did not work, 2) still the same error message.

Comment: @Jeeped tried that also and getting the same error like before

Answer (score 0):

three problems with your code

1. You can't use a reserved key like "Date" as a variable
2. Possibly you are including the headers in the loop, while adding date
3. in the firs line of your loop, you should use something like SomeRange.Rows

Comment: To 2. I used the code from answer one and changed the RowCount start from 1 to 2 so it would not start in line 1 where the header stands. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Besides `Date` being a reserved word (as mentioned in the comments), you can use the simpler code version below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, RowCount As Long
    Dim MyDate As Date

    RowCount = 0
    Set sh = Sheets("Table1")
    With sh
        RowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row  '<-- get last row in column 'A"

        For i = 1 To RowCount
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then Exit For

            MyDate = DateAdd("d", 1, .Cells(i, 4).Value)
            Debug.Print MyDate
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Getting the same error number 13 in the line MyDate = DateAdd("d", 1, .Cells(i, 4).Value). Tried it also with CDate like suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
Sub test()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim RowCount As Integer
    Dim NewDate As Date 'New added

    RowCount = 0
    Set sh = Sheets("Table1")

    For Each rw In sh.Rows

        If sh.Cells(rw.Row, 4).Value = "" Then
            Exit For
        End If

       NewDate = DateAdd("d", 1, sh.Cells(rw.Row, 4).Value) 'Change Date to NewDate
       Debug.Print NewDate 'Change Date to NewDate

    Next rw
End Sub
```